# BigQuery REGEX function to get text between 2 characters

Tags: regex, re2

In this sentence  'please contact at delivery@good.com for any details' I want to extract email. In real sentence there are many emails but I only want to extract emails starting from 'contact at' and ending at 'for any'. length of emails can be varied.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Tyson,

You can use the `REGEXP_EXTRACT()` [function in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract) with the REGEX pattern of `([a-zA-Z0-9+._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)` to extract just the email address from your data.

Full example:

```sql
WITH data AS(
  SELECT "please contact at delivery@good.com for any details" AS sample_row
)

SELECT *
, REGEXP_EXTRACT(sample_row, "([a-zA-Z0-9+._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)") AS extracted_email
FROM data
```

Note that for BigQuery you have to double-escape the `\` character.

Comment: I only want to extract email starting from 'contact at' and ending at 'for any'. extract the string(email) between  'contact at' and  'for any' characters

Comment: Can you share an example of the desired output please? The code above does capture what's between these strings, so long as it is an email, are you looking for something different?